# While loop won't break on bool C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I don't understand why my while loop won't stop looping when I assign a bool variable (gameEnded) to `true`.

```
Board board = new Board();
bool gameEnded = false;
while (!gameEnded)
{
    gameEnded = board.DrawCheck(board); //one of these three methods returns true
    gameEnded = board.WinCheckO(board);
    gameEnded = board.WinCheckX(board);

    Render(board);
    bool turnO = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Player X's turn.");
    //... here some code that gets executed right
}
```

So, gameEnded boolean variable should be assigned a value of true, and the loop, therefore, break. I checked that Check*something* methods return true.
The modified version works just fine, that is, breaks the loop.

```
Board board = new Board();
bool gameEnded = false;
while (!gameEnded)
{

    if (board.WinCheckX(board))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("X player won!");
         break;
     }
     else if (board.WinCheckO(board))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("O player won!");
         break;
     }
     else if (board.DrawCheck(board))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("It's a tie!");
         break;
     }

    Render(board);
    bool turnO = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Player X's turn.");
        //... here some code that gets executed right
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: first fragment: only last assigning is important, first and second have no result

Comment: This is something you could easily have discovered but stepping the the code in debug, by the way. You would have seen the flag being set to true, and then to false again. F10 and F11 are your friends!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> //one of these three methods returns true
> ```

Because there are three assignments, it is not enough for one of these methods to return `true`: only the last assignment has any effect, so unless `board.WinCheckX(board)` returns `true`, the loop continues.

The fix is straightforward: combine three assignments into one with `||` operator:

```
gameEnded = board.DrawCheck(board)
      || board.WinCheckO(board)
      || board.WinCheckX(board);
```

An added benefit of this approach is that as soon as one of these methods returns `true`, there would be no additional calls due to short-circuiting of `||` operator.

Comment: The check should also by run at the end of the loop... no need to continue the loop if the game is over!